# Creating a music streaming app from a "http" url

Tags: java, android, url, uri, android-mediaplayer

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity  {

MediaPlayer mPlayer;
String radio;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

    radio = "http://s26.myradiostream.com:9406/listen.pls";

  mPlayer.setDataSource(this , Uri.parse(radio));


}
```

}

I am trying to stream the music from this `url`. I set up a media player and when i go to "`setDataSource`" it asks for (context, and Uri uri)...what am i doing wrong. I parsed the string to a `uri`. Am i going in the right direction? what should i do?!?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code will be use to play url using media Player:

```
String  radioUrl = "http://s26.myradiostream.com:9406/listen.pls";

        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(radioUrl);
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
        mediaPlayer.start();
```

Comment: yes i have tried that but it still didn't work. any more suggestions? is the url that i am using formatted wrong??. you should try it out yourself and see if you can get it to work. just a thought. Thanks for your hlep!!

Comment: As you are playing pls file And A .pls file is just a playlist. There is no media there. You will have the parse the file yourself to get the actual stream URLs. Open it up in a text editor to see what I mean.